# Converting each image in image collection to separate bands with band names in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, stack

How do I create a stacked image from an image collection of Sentinel 1 images over a period?

I am selecting only the ascending mode, and the VH polarization. If I use ".toBands()" at the end of the coding, it is creating a stacked image. However, the band names are quite long mentioning their properties, like "S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_....VH". I want the names to be like "b1", "b2"....and so on.

I am using the following code:

```
// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var sentinel1A = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                    .filterDate('2021-06-01', '2021-11-16')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING')))
                    .select('VH')
                    .filterBounds(ROI)
                    .toBands();


print (sentinel1A, 'S1A');
Map.addLayer(sentinel1A, {}, 'S1A');
```

Comment: Could you describe what you intend to do with the output of `toBands()`? That _might_ help lead to a better solution that avoids the problem by avoiding `toBands()`.

Comment: Actually, I want a stacked image of all the dates available in that image collection. Suppose, that the image collection has imageries of 5 dates. I want an image with the bands described as band1=date1, band 2=date 2and so on. Finally, I want the backscatter coefficient for particular pixels from the stacked image.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a list with the band names you are going to use to replace the current image/band names. The list has to be the same length as the number of bands.

```
var names = ee.List.sequence(0,sentinel1A.bandNames().size().subtract(1))
  .map(function(element){
    return ee.String('b').cat(ee.Number(element).toInt())
  });
```

Then once you have that list you simply apply the .rename() function like this:

```
var sentinel1ARenamed = sentinel1A.rename(names);
print(sentinel1ARenamed);
```

Comment: You are right, although this is a commentary instead of an answer. Please elaborate it

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little with the above code I provided? If there are 14 images in the collection, how do I convert only one polarized channel, e.g., VH of all the 14 images into 14 bands and stack them to create a 14 band image? Where should I use the .rename() command?

Comment: @SwadhinaKoley I've edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Excellent, now this is a great answer

Comment: @M. Nicolas Thank you so much!

Comment: @SwadhinaKoley I'm glad it worked! Could you accept the answer? :) Thanks!